# Angular 2 Observable single value from arrow function

Tags: angular, observable, arrow-functions

I have the following code in my component:

```
  private katalog : Katalog;
  private allKatalogs : Katalog[] = [];

  constructor(private adminService : AdminService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.adminService.get_kataloge().subscribe((items : Katalog[]) => this.allKatalogs = items);
    this.adminService.get_kataloge().subscribe((items : Katalog[]) => this.katalog = items[0]);
  }
  showObject() {
    console.log(this.katalog); // this returns undefined
    console.log(this.allKatalogs); // this returns [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
  }
```

Why is `this.katalog` undefined?

here the service:

```
get_kataloge() : Observable<Katalog[]> { return this.kataloge.asObservable(); }
```

the katalog model:

```
export class Katalog {
    _id: string;
    bezeichnung: string;
}
```

template html

```
<p (click)="showObject()">show object</p>
```

Comment: What is the type of :Katalog;?

Comment: can you show the katalog class or interface ?

Comment: where is `showObject()` called?

Comment: also, you should place `showObject()` inside the `ngOnInit()` or in `ngAfterViewInit()`

Comment: @tholo, well we don't know when OP wants to execute `showObject()`, so placing it inside something might be wrong here :)

Comment: Your subscribing to an Observable twice. Which put basically means it already "gave up" the value once. That means it's `undefined` the next time round since nothing is there. The approach here is flawed and you would do better to describe what you are trying to do overall.

Comment: @AJT_82, that's true. My point was that he can only execute it after the order that he already defined in `ngOnInit()`

Comment: @tholo Yes I understand what you mean :) and on the other hand, this is probably just a function to debug the app, just like Neil pointed out.

Comment: @tholo, thanks for your help, yes its just for debugging that i subscribe the Observable twice

Comment: @suraj i call it in the html template by (click)

Comment: It works with this line this.adminService.get_kataloge().subscribe(
        function (data) {
          if (data) {
            console.log(data[0]);
          }
        }
    );

Comment: the whole issue could be async nature of the call

Comment: @suraj yes your are right, when i put the subscript to the showObject() i get the right result, but I need in the ngOnInit(). So I try to work with a promise